# Applying match_phrase and filter

Tags: elasticsearch

Worked on Elastic Search 6.4.2. I want to use `match_pharse`to get the retrieve the results from my index. In the same way I need to apply the filter for that. Any solution for this. I tried the below query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": 
        {
          "match_phrase": {
          "title": "bike riding"
          }}

    }
  }}
```

But When I using `match_pharse` I need to pass the fields  in order to get the results. I am sharing my mapping  and query that I need to be edited. Any help that I can use the `match_phrase` for a query.

Mapping:

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "content": {
          "type": "text",
          "store": true,
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        },
        "description": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "domain": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "host": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "store": true
        },
        "keywords": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "seed": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "store": true
        },
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "store": true,
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        },
        "url": {
          "type": "text",
          "store": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`
```

Query:
How can I add `match_phrase` to the below one

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "query_string" : {
                    "query" : "bike riding"
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "term" : { "seed" : "sports" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below query is what you would be looking for.

Notice how I've added quotes around `"\"bike riding\""`

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "query_string" : {
                    "query" : "\"bike riding\""
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "term" : { "seed": "sports" }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Hi @Kamal, I tried your query Its gave null values and in filter I removed `.keyword `for the field name that works exactly as I expected.

Comment: Yup yup, sorry about that :) Nevertheless, I'm glad it worked once you removed `.keyword`.